# Array2XML - Duplicated tags names are being ignored

Tags: php, xml

I am using Array2XML with PHP to create XML from an array.

Here is the code where tags are duplicated:

```
"positions" => array(
   "position" => "top_centre",
   "position" => "centre_left",
   "position" => "centre_right",
   "position" => "bottom_centre"
);
```

I can see the issue here is that the values are being overwritten, so the XML displays like this:

```
  <positions>
    <position>bottom_centre</position>
  </positions>
```

How can I use Array2XML to display it like this instead?:

```
<positions>
   <position>top_centre</position>
   <position>centre_left</position>
   <position>centre_right</position>
   <position>bottom_centre</position>
</positions>
```

---

EDIT:
Fixed the issue, just needed to use another array:

```
"positions" => array(
   "position" => array("top_centre", "centre_left", "centre_right", "bottom_centre")
)
```

Comment: http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/

Comment: I fixed my own issue, I had to create another array for the values, found using Google and the link above.

Comment: Can you close this question by answering it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, just needed to use another array:

```
"positions" => array(
   "position" => array("top_centre", "centre_left", "centre_right", "bottom_centre")
)
```